# Files created with Google Drive API are owned by the Service Account

Tags: google-drive-api

When I create a file with Google Drive API in my private Drive, it is owned by my Service Account and by default not accessible with my primary account unless I add a new permission. Even then, my actions are somewhat limited, e.g. I cannot delete it. Assuming it occupies space on my Drive, it's kind of weird.

What is the common way around this? Ownership transfer?

Comment: You answered your own question, yes transfer the permissions.  By default if you use a service account it will be the owner.

Comment: @easleyfixed All right, I wasn't sure, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I clearly misunderstood how this works.

The Service Account is a separate entity operating in the Google Cloud project scope, completely isolated from my private Drive.

In that case, I find it safer to let it own the files and add standard permissions as necessary. As long as the project is alive and the quota is not exceeded, it is not an issue.

Comment: Service accounts have limited space in their account and it cant be extended.

Answer (score 0):

When you share a directory in your drive with someone and the upload a file to it the results are the same.

The person or the account doing the uploading is the owner of said file.  The same goes with a service account.

When uploading files using a service account to your own person a drive account you must remember to grant your personal account ownership or at the very least permissions on the file.

Comment: I'm not sure it's the same thing. I'm not even sure that it secretly occupies space, or even operates on my Drive at this point.  Yet the Service Account is created from the main account, which is incredibly confusing, and likely an effect of service downgrading.

Comment: You can test it if you want by doing an about.get.  it should show where the storage is alcoated

Comment: Yep, it's clearly a different space, likely owned by the Google Cloud project in which the Service Account has been created.